# onCreate in main class extends Application never called

Tags: android

I have a weird problem. My application classes onCreate (or onReusume) is never called. Even if i deinstall the app and debug agan.
Here is my code. I cannot find any strange in it. If I set a breaktpoint it is never reached and other classes tell me that the init fails.
Tanks

```
package com.MyApp;

import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;
import android.app.Application;


@ReportsCrashes(formKey = ".................") 
public class MyApp extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    public void onCreate() {
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            ACRA.init(this);
        }
```

this is my xml:

```
<application
        android:name="com.MyApp.MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme" >
        <activity android:name="com.MyApp.MyApp.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter> ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this it will work

```
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
    ACRA.init(this);
    super.onCreate();
  }
```

you forget to call `super.onCreate();`

Comment: super.oncreate comes later in my code. i had a override in before without luck. the thing is i had a line breakpoint on if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) { which of corse never got called. thanks for your reply